# Download APK not working in Chrome browser

Tags: java, android, google-chrome

My website has an option to download the apk file. The file is getting correctly downloaded in all other Android browsers except Chrome.

Getting a warning as "Resource interpreted as document but transfered with Mime type application / octet-stream". I have implemented below code but it is not working.

Java code:

```
String filename = 'Sample.apk';
String filepath = '/resources/mobileapp/';
MimetypesFileTypeMap mimetypesFileTypeMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
response.setContentType(mimetypesFileTypeMap.getContentType(filepath + filename));
response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\");
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the server is sending a Javascript HTTP response with

> ```
> Content-Type: text/plain
> ```

You need to configure the server to send a JavaScript response with

> ```
>   Content-Type: application/javascript
> ```